# Disabling wake on mouse, etc

Tags: 20.04, suspend, mouse, power-management, wakeup

I am using Lubuntu 20.04.3.
Trying to disable wake on (USB) mouse (and actually, I would only keep Power button and Lid), I found

```
$ grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-3/product:USB2.0-CRW
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-4/product:TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD
/sys/bus/usb/devices/6-2/product:USB Receiver
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/product:EHCI Host Controller
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/product:EHCI Host Controller
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/product:EHCI Host Controller
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb4/product:OHCI PCI host controller
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb5/product:OHCI PCI host controller
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb6/product:OHCI PCI host controller

$ grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-3/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/6-2/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb3/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb4/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb5/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb6/power/wakeup:disabled

$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
PB6       S4    *disabled
SPB1      S5    *disabled  pci:0000:00:15.1
SPB2      S4    *disabled
SPB3      S4    *disabled
OHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:12.0
OHC3      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:16.0
EHC1      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:12.2
EHC3      S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:16.2
XHC0      S3    *disabled
P2P       S5    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.4
LID0      S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
```

**Isn't the information contradicting?**

All items in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup` show `disabled`, but `/proc/acpi/wakeup` shows some `enabled` (besides `LID0`, which I assume is the lid).

---

I am just checking in another system, and I see the same

```
$ grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/product:2.4G Office Mouse
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-8/product:Integrated Camera
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/product:xHCI Host Controller
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/product:xHCI Host Controller

$ grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-14/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-9/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup:disabled

$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep enabled
PEG0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.0
XHC   S3    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
RP08      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.7
RP09      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
SLPB      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0E:00
LID   S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
```

Comment: You're corrrect... /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup doesn't show any enabled. /proc/acpi/wakeup enabled devices are the controllers. Is yours a Logitech mouse, with a USB dongle?

Comment: I don't know the technical answer to this but if you want to disable something in `/proc/acpi/wakeup` then do: `sudo -s` followed by (for example) `echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup` to toggle from enabled to disabled and vice-versa. Which is exactly what I had to do to stop USB devices waking my laptop from suspend after a few seconds without even being touched.

Comment: @heynnema - Yes.

Comment: Yes what? Logitech with unifying USB receiver? Have you done the firmware update for the receiver?

Comment: @heynnema - Yes, Logitech M325 with USB dongle. No, I have not updated the firmware (I didn't know there was anything available for that). Does this explain anything?
For the second system that I added (Ubuntu 20.04.3), the mouse is also a Bluetooth with USB dongle, Power Gear 42253.

Comment: Update the Logitech unifying receiver firmware. You **MUST** reboot the system to repopulate /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup with the proper enabled/disabled wakeup status.